# Cannot drop incoming packets of an interface using iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to drop incoming packets of an interface, with a specific probability, using iptables.

I've been using:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

And everything works as expected. However, as I also want to specify the interface, I tried:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -i eth1 -j DROP
```

but when I do, the rule is simply ignored.

What would be the correct way to drop incoming packets of an interface, using iptables or other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me.

The interesting thing is that it **works** for IPv6: `alice` pings `bob`, which has the drop rule in place:

First, without the rule (edited to remove real addresses!)

```
alice# ping6 -f bob
PING XXXX 56 data bytes
.^C
--- XXXX ping statistics ---
4798 packets transmitted, 4797 received, 0% packet loss, time 4274ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.435/1.143/203.132/6.988 ms, pipe 17, ipg/ewma 0.890/0.679 ms
```

Install the rule on `bob`:

```
bob# ip6tables -i eth1 -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

Run the test again on `alice`:

```
alice# $ sudo ping6 -f bob
PING XXXX 56 data bytes
.......................................................^C
--- XXXX ping statistics ---
1003 packets transmitted, 906 received, 9% packet loss, time 2324ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.461/0.907/21.699/0.993 ms, pipe 2, ipg/ewma 2.319/0.811 ms
```

I'll try to remember to check the source later. Meanwhile, we should file a bug.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know if it is a bug or simply a capability that was not implemented on iptables... It's still annoying, though.